Only able to get some the calendar events in R via googleAuthR
I'm trying to download google calendar events into R from various shared calendars, and it appears that for some calendars the events stop loading. Some calendars have events until the present day while others stop about a year ago, when they clearly have new events that have been created since then. The max number of events per calendar tends to be around 250, so I don't know if it's being throttled.
Here's an example of the code I'm using. It got it from here: https://gist.github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/0198e283cd228565f9313cf36f35c7ab

library(googleAuthR)

options(googleAuthR.scopes.selected = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
        googleAuthR.client_id = "xxxxx", 
        googleAuthR.client_secret = "xxxxx")  
#gar_auth()
events.list <- function(calendarId = "primary") {
  url <- sprintf("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%s/events", 
                 calendarId)
  
  f <- googleAuthR::gar_api_generator(url, "GET", 
                                      data_parse_function = function(x) x)
  f()
  
}

events <- lapply(calendar_ids, events.list)


Okay the answer is to do this:
f <- googleAuthR::gar_api_generator(url, "GET",
data_parse_function = function(x) x,
pars_args = list(maxResults = 100000))
